# How to create nested menu with pyTelegramBotAPI?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I am creating my own telegram bot with `pyTelegramBotAPI`. And I wonder how to create nested menu with inline buttons. Here is good example of what I want to create, this is `BotFather`, bot, that allows you to create tokes for your bots. As you can see, you work in only one "message", because this is menu.

[image]

So, could you please provide me a minimal working example of that menu? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be done with `edit_message_text` method. Here is example:

```py
...
keyboard = [[types.InlineKeyboardButton("< Go back", callback_data='smt')]]
markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
...
```

```py
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def commandshandlebtn(call):
    userMessage = call.data
    if userMessage == "smt":
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text='Some text, for example')
```